# SugarCRM, displaying data as HTML in DetailView

Tags: php, tinymce, richtextbox, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM, have tried to use the Rich Text Editor for the fields using TinyMCE and it stores and renders properly in EditView but in ListView and DetailView the output displaying with tags instead of formatting.

in database its storing with HTML tags as expected. I am looking solution how to render formatting in detailview section.

[image]

In Detail View

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to decode the HTML characters in Smarty in `customCode` in `DetailViewDefs.php` file.

```php
   'name' => 'editor_c',
        'studio' => 'visible',
   'customCode' => '{$fields.editor_c.value|escape:\'htmlentitydecode\' |escape:\'html\'|strip_tags|url2html|nl2br}',
```